# How to add custom block in PDP Page PWA Magento 2

Tags: magento2, graphql, magento2.4.6, pwa, pwa-studio

I've recently embarked on the journey of learning about Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) and GraphQL. However, I'm facing challenges in finding beginner-friendly resources, particularly regarding topics like adding custom blocks to a Product Detail Page (PDP) in PWAs. I did come across a video on the subject, but it seems to modify the default file.

**Example:**

I have found a video to add a custom field in the customer registration form but my question how can I do this with my custom extension similar to how we do it in Magento?

[How to add customer custom attributes in PWA Magento](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8UdSA4hlxU)

I'm curious if there's a way to override this file similar to how we do it in Magento. Any guidance or resources you could recommend for someone at my level would be greatly appreciated.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Are you using your own custom form or the existing Magento form?

Comment: Default Magento form

Comment: Which default form?